# How can I separate strings line by line in Java?

Tags: java

```
Spring Street, 101/12
Postal Code: 8001
State: Washington
```

How can I separate line by line as in the example above?

```
address.setAddress(MessageFormat.format(
        "{0} {1} Postal Code: {2}, State: {3}",restSmeApplication.getAddress(),restSmeApplication.getStreet() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "",restSmeApplication.getPostalCode(),restSmeApplication.getState() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "")
);
```

Comment: Just put `\n` characters into the string?

Comment: "{0}\n {1}\n Postal Code: {2}\n, State: {3}\n"   like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` will work for you -

```
address.setAddress(MessageFormat.format(
            "{0} \n {1} Postal Code: {2}, \n State: {3}",restSmeApplication.getAddress(),restSmeApplication.getStreet() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "",restSmeApplication.getPostalCode(),restSmeApplication.getState() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```java
address.setAddress(String.format(
        "%s %s \n Postal Code: %s,\n State: %s",
restSmeApplication.getAddress(),restSmeApplication.getStreet() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "",restSmeApplication.getPostalCode(),restSmeApplication.getState() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MessageFormat is a heavy object.
For the intent of formatting the string one could use a static method `String.format()` which follows a printf() syntax and allows more options for formatting.
`%n` or `\n` can be used to make a new line.

```
String addressAsString = 
    String.format("%s %s%nPostal Code: %s,%nState: %s",
        restSmeApplication.getAddress(),
        restSmeApplication.getStreet() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "",
        restSmeApplication.getPostalCode(),restSmeApplication.getState() != null ? restSmeApplication.getStreet(): "");
address.setAddress(addressAsString);
```

Keep in mind that line is not synonym to string. And the resulting sting is still one single string. We just insert some additional formatting into it so to make it's representation to be multi-line.